# ASP.NET WebAPI XML Serialization after RC update

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5

Prior to the asp.net 4 RC update, I had been using the WebApi for outputting XML. My model had XmlSerialization attributes `[XmlElement(ElementName = "the name")]` so that I could use friendlier names.

e.g.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Branch")]
public string site_nm { get; set; }
```

After the .net 4 RC update, the XML which is output ignores this.

I know that some things have changed in the WebApi, like to make a method return values based on OData protocols when returning `IQueryable<T>`, you now need to add `[Queryable]` to your methods.

Is there something that I need to add to make the serialization work? I have read through change notes but can't see anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instruct the formatter to use XmlSerializer:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

The default now is the DataContractSerializer.

Comment: If the default is now DataContractSerializer, how can I make use of this instead? [DataMember(Name="the name)] ?

Comment: Ahh i got it. thanks. Just going to use [DataContact(Name="")] and [DataMember(Name="")] now.